# Decrease size of a avi video with lowest quality loss

Tags: conversion, compression, render

I have been working on an animation with Blender. Further I rendered it at 24 fps at 1080p resolution.

The problem is that the rendered video is around 30 seconds and has size around **4.3 GB**.

Is there any way to decrease the size without losing much quality?

Comment: What do you mean by "is to m " Stib

Comment: What is to m???

Answer (score 1):

Now you've actually finished your question, the simple answer is to encode it using h.264/mp4. Blender can render to h.264, using ffmpeg video in the render settings but the better way is to render to image sequences and convert.

Since you have a render, you can convert it to h.264 / mp4 without having to re-render. There are many ways to do this, [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) being one of the best, but if you prefer a GUI then [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is a good option.